# How to Make Kendo grid as readonly for particular user

Tags: html, css, kendo-grid

i have a Kendo grid with selectable sortable columns i want to make this entire grid to Read only option for particular user how to make this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the editable field in the kendogrid object to false based on the current user.
Following is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/8KwNN/5/

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds,
    editable: false,
    columns: [{
        field: "FirstName",
        width: 90,
        title: "First Name"
    }]
});
```

Of course, you'll need to ensure that your service operations (which can apply updates via AJAX calls from the client, for example) do not allow updates for the restricted user.  This is done because we never trust any client (even if it's running our javascript).